# problems getting selenium standalone server to work with phpunit

Tags: java, php, selenium-webdriver, phpunit, fedora-25

I am trying to get newer versions selenium standalone server to work with phpunit. What I have works, but I'm required to updated selenium standalone server to 3.0.1.

Currently, I am running:

1. selenium standalone server            2.53.0
2. phpunit                               4.6.7
3. fedora 25 VM on my Windows desktop
4. php                                   7.0.14
5. apache                                2.4.25
6. java                                  1.8.0_111
7. Facebook php-webdriver – Selenium WebDriver bindings for PHP

Here is sample php that works:

```
<?php
    class Example extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
    {
        protected function setUp()
        {
            $this->setBrowser("*chrome");
            $this->setBrowser("http://my.url.com/");
        }

        public function testMyTestCase()
        {
            $this->open("/");
        }
    }
?>
```

If I use phpunit 5.7.6 (the latest version) I get the error:

> PHP Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase' not found in ...

I get no error (that I can find) from selenium server. If I then change selenium to 3.0.1 (the latest) leaving phpunit at 5.7.6, I get same error.

If I leave selenium server at 3.0.1 and change phpunit to 4.6.7, I get a bizarre error:

> Invalid response while accessing the Selenium Server at 'http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/': ...

Where in place of the ellipsis, I am given a lot of html code for what appears to be a selenium server help page. It contains:

```
<div id="content-body">
    <p>
        Whoops! The URL specified routes to this help page.
    </p>
</div>
```

At this point, I'm stuck. It appears that I cannot get phpunit to talk successfully with selenium server. I'm required to upgrade selenium standalone server to 3.0.1 and phpunit to 4.6.7. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your `phpunit-selenium` and extend instead from

`PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase`

Also, phpunit 4.6* is not supported for PHP 7 so you will need to upgrade from that anyway.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what does this mean: "You need to upgrade your phpunit-selenium". Higher ups have dictated that I have to upgrade selenium server to the latest version, but I have to keep phpunit at the version I am currently using.

Comment: There's a few things wrong: as mentioned, your PHP + PHPUnit versions are not compatible; you state you are using facebook php webdriver, but in your sample code you are using an *old* version of `phpunit-selenium` and you don't even touch facebook web driver. Fix the PHP + PHPUnit incompatibility first.

Comment: OK. I am now using

Comment: I was trying to get the old version phpunit to work because that is what my cloud service provider said I had to use. Be that as it may, I'd like to try to get the most recent versions working. Maybe I can convince them to upgrade. I am now using php 5.6.30, selenium server 3.0.1 and phpunit 5.7.13. I get this error: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase' not found in ... What am I doing wrong now? Googled on the error. No change using "require_once".

Comment: I had installed the facebook webdrivers using "php composer.phar require facebook/webdriver". I got no errors, and the vendor/facebook directory is there. I cannot find the PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase class anywhere.